# Handle form created in code (WinForms)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, events, basic

I ran into a little problem. With this piece of code, I create a **new** form for every ".jpg" file in a folder:

```
Dim d As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("path to folder")

For Each bild As FileInfo In d.GetFiles("*.jpg")

    Dim p As New Form
    p.Show()

Next
```

Now I have some trouble handling the forms (p) event. I know how to handle forms that were created in code but this doesn't work if more then one form were created. Just the last one gets the events.

```
AddHandler p.Click, AddressOf p_click()
```

In short: How can every form get the event (p_click) when multiple forms are created in code?

Comment: Can you show where exactly in the code you are calling `AddHandler`?  If you are doing it inside the loop, it should work.

Comment: are you trying to get one form to service the clicks on another?  also `Form` is always going to be a basic empty form

Comment: @StevenDoggart Yes I'm calling AddHandler right before p.Show() Do you need further informations?

Comment: @Plutonix No, the p_click Sub is just a sample. The form is edited in my original code so its not empty. I could post the original code but its a little bit long :P

Comment: Mybe I should ask differtently: The form (f) is created inside a loop. So how can I refer to f in the Subs which act as handler (like p_click) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes I'm calling AddHandler right before p.Show()

That's correct then...you cast the `sender` parameter in the handler to get a reference to the Form:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim d As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyPictures)
    For Each bild As FileInfo In d.GetFiles("*.jpg")
        Dim p As New Form
        AddHandler p.Click, AddressOf p_Click
        p.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(bild.FullName)
        p.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom
        p.Show()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub p_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim frm As Form = DirectCast(sender, Form)
    ' ... do something with "frm" ...
    frm.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you, you just finished my little project :)

Comment: If your adding handlers make sure to remove them as well. Otherwise it can create unhandle memory issues...